# Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: android, eclipse

eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
i had delete my eclipse and Sdk also because they did not generate R.java file so i think delete the eclipse and then extract the  eclipse zip after extract the zip then i click it show that error  "eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library".How to solve  this problem . i read the many article but did not find the best solution .My laptop configuration is dual core 3 gb ram 320 hd ,32bit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip again. Make sure that your unzip tool extracts directories. This error is typical for unzipping to a flat folder structure.

Comment: ya sir , but i think it zip of eclipse is corrupt ,because other zip file working well .@Bananeweize

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too, because I tried to run the eclipse before the unzip process has finished.

Make sure that the unzip process has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that library 
**org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_.dist.jar**
and 
**plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_.dist**
exists on your system.

Make sure that the version of libraries mentioned in eclipse.ini and the version that exists on your system is same. Usually after upgrade this mismatch occurs and eclipse fails to locate the required jar.
Please take a look at this blog post [here](http://codewithgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/11/fixing-eclipse-executable-launcher-was.html)

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse.ini, I noticed some paths contained dashes, which denote a new arguement.  It is a simple fix:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar   
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
```

must be:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v201404152008.jar   
--launcher.library
```

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v201502041316

But, you must also do the same to the actual files.  Hope this helps!